# SwiftUI - Navigation Link pops out on iPhone, but not in Simulator

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have an app that contains several views with NavigationLinks inside.

The main view looks like this, calling a Toolbar view I have created.

```swift
struct CountListView: View {
    @StateObject var vm = CountListViewModel()
    let navigationBar = HomePageNavigationBar()

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(vm.count, id: \.uid) { item in
                    NavigationLink(destination: CountView(count: item)) {
                        CountListItemView(name: item.name)
                    }
                }
            }
            .toolbar {
                navigationBar.rightSideOfBar()
                navigationBar.leftSideOfBar()
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Count")
```

The navigation bar function that is playing up looks like this

```swift
    func leftSideOfBar() -> some ToolbarContent {
        ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
            NavigationLink(destination: SettingsView()) {
                Label("Settings", systemImage: "gear")
            }
        }
    }
```

And the SettingsView is as follows:

```swift
struct SettingsView: View {
    var body: some View {
      List {
        NavigationLink(destination: NameSettingView()) {
          Text("Name")
      }
        .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())

        NavigationLink(destination: PrivacyPolicyView()) {
          Text("Privacy Policy")
      }
        .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())

    }
      .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
   }
}
```

When I open the Privacy Policy View on device, the returns to the SettingsView without any user intervention. But this problem doesn't exist in the simulator.

Comment: Is there data being actively fetched or updated during the lifecycle of your app?

Comment: In the CountListView, yes. But there isn't any fetching/updating in the SettingsView

Comment: How does the PrivacyPolicyView look like?